# C++ template class crashing by uint8_t type only

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, uint8t

I've just found this interesting issue in one of my older projects.
I'd defined a class wrapped around an std::shared_ptr to implement a simple dynamic array as you can see below:

```
#include <memory>

template<class Type>
class Array
{
  size_t                m_size;
  std::shared_ptr<Type> m_array;

public:
  Array()
    : m_size( 0 )
    , m_array( nullptr, []( Type * p ){ delete[] p; } )
    {}

  Array( const size_t size )
    : m_size( size )
    , m_array( new Type[size] {}, []( Type * p ){ delete[] p; } )
    {}

  Type & operator[]( const size_t & id )
  {
    return m_array.get()[id];
  }

  const Type & operator[]( const size_t & id ) const
  {
    return m_array.get()[id];
  }

  Type * get()
  {
    return m_array.get();
  }

  const Type * get() const
  {
    return m_array.get();
  }

  size_t size() const
  {
    return m_size;
  }

  Array & operator= ( const Array<Type> array )
  {
    m_size  = array.size();
    m_array = array.m_array;
    return *this;
  };
};
```

And it worked fine beside uint8_t :

```
Array<int>  Int;      // good
Array<long> Long;     // good
Array<char> Char;     // good
Array<int8_t> Int8;   // good
Array<uint8_t> Uint8; // segmentation fault

int main() 
{ 
 // create scoped array 
  { 
    Array<uint8_t> pattern; 
  } 

// do something

return 0;
}
```

No member function was called beside the constructor.
Does anyone any idea why happening this? The compiler is:
gcc9.2.0-rhel7.6-binutils2.32.gold

Thanks,

Comment: Could you include a main that triggers the segfault? Or is it literally just `int main() { Array<uint8_t> x; }`

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Type[]>` will automatically use `delete[]`. Then you don't need to pass a custom deleter. And it also enables `operator[]` directly on the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: can't [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/ddP5hdE8T)

Comment: hi!

of course:

```
int main()
{
  // scoped array
  {
    Array<uint8_t> pattern;
  }
}
```

Is it possible the fault of compiler ? On other system and with  gcc10.2.1 it seems work fine.

Comment: What are your compilation flags, please?

Comment: Nothing special, I use cmake:


cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/path/to/compiler "proj-name" .. && make

Comment: wow, is it possible the different versions of gcc and g++ can make such an error? Unfortunately, I can't change settings now to try.

Comment: Obfuscating your answers doesn't help, like writing `/path/to/compiler` instead of the actual full path.

Comment: are you perhaps using different versions of libstdc++ in different parts of your project resulting in a ODR violation?

Comment: cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/proj/epg-tools/compilers/gcc9.2.0-rhel7.6-binutils2.32.gold/bin/g++ "proj-name" ..

where th CC version is:
cc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

Comment: Concerning that repeated lambda `[]( Type * p ){ delete[] p; } ` -- writing the same code twice is a sign of trouble, since you now have two places to maintain; the usual solution is to put the code into a function.

Answer (score 0):

Using different versions of compiler and libstdc++ caused the problem. Issue fixed, thank you for your questions and tips. They were really helpful.